# CSS: Combining display:flex and overflow:auto kills padding

Tags: css, flexbox, scrollbar, padding

I'm using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) to display a dynamic list of child `div`'s inside a parent container, allowing the user to scroll through them if there are too many. I want some space between the children and the parent, so I have set `padding: 25px` on the parent. This padding is however not applied on the right side of the parent `div`. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.parent {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.child {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2f4154s0/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2f4154s0/5/